# Import Query into Windows Grep tool

Tags: windows, grep

I've been using grepWin,

And I would like to somehow perform a series of queries for pdf links within .html files.
Thus far with the tool I have been using I just input each individual PDF name and copy the file paths of each reference.

This works fine but I have several hundred specific PDFs I need to find the references for,

And I was wondering if this was possible by using Cygwin or some other cmdline like Findstr to pipe a textfile of links to PDF's which I am searching.

I will give an example:

Spring-Summer.pdf

I would copy all of the paths to which the listed file is linked to within html files.

I then need that copied next to it, or in its own column within csv.

I'm not sure if it's at all probable anyone has asked this before. Currently I'm filling out a spreadsheet of links to these files for a website..

Answer (score 0):

In Linux the following command will find all the html files which contain the specified string:

```
grep -Rl "Spring-Summer.pdf" <some root folder>
```

The -R option is to search recursively, and -l is to display just the file name without content.
The same should work on Cygwin.